# What is going on with java.nio.charset.Charsets?

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, dalvik

So, as far as I can tell, this class doesn't exist in the standard Java library and is an addition in Dalvik. Is this correct?

My reason for thinking this is the android class "NdefRecord" contains reference to it and uses it but there is no way of importing it into a standard Java project (that I can find).

Is there any way to import this class to an Android project?

Where can I find it's up-to-date content, as used by the android project?

Comment: Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html

Comment: check the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Comment: thanks both. Raghunandan, I cannot find any real reference to the Charsets class there.

@SLaks interesting, thanks. I wonder why this isnt used. I've found sample code from google (in android-15 samples for NdefDemo) that use this: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.nio.charset.Charsets`, which is different from `Charset`, is unique to Dalvik.  If you look at the comment header [in the source file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/java/nio/charset/Charsets.java) you will see:

```
@hide internal use only
```

This means it is not part of the public API, and should not be used by applications.  If you decide to use it anyway, you will need to access it through reflection.

Comment: thanks. so the usage I need for it is pretty simple (essentially the same as in the NdefRecord class) - ie equivalent to Charset.forName() which I will use instead. But why bother with this extra separation and compatibility risk for public API users? The internal conversion from string to byte[] in NdefRecord uses `new String(str, Charsets.UTF_8)`, so why not either return a string, use Charset.forName() or make Charsets part of the public API?

Comment: I don't know.  If you look at the change history (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+log/master/luni/src/main/java/java/nio/charset/Charsets.java) you can see some fairly detailed notes about why the class was created and how it's used.

Comment: OK. seems to be perhaps something to do with performance.

good answer and comment help. thanks alot. +1